# testing difference in distributions with population values (using python)

Tags: python, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, population

I am looking for the best method to test for a difference between two distributions.

I have data from a patient group, and my aim is to compare the distribution to a reference distribution. However, the reference distribution is not theoretical, it is based on census data and I have it as well. The patient sample is drawn from the census population data, but within the census data, I do not know who is a patient and who is not. Additionally, the distribution refers to counts. There is a scale of values from 0 to 80, and I am counting how many residents vs. how many patients score 1, or 2, or 3... up to 80. This means that in *absolute values* the census vs. patient distributions appear very different (one is in millions, the other in thousands), but I want to know if they are similar in *shape*.

I initially thought the simplest approach would be to use a 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but there are several reasons why I hesitate, and would like to hear if there are better approaches:

- The 2-sample KS-test assumes that both samples are drawn from the same population, but here one of my samples *is* the population
- The 2-sample KS-test assumes that the samples are either dependent or independent, whereas here they are partially dependent (all patients are in the census data as well)

I think that the better approach, therefore, might be to use a 1-sample KS test, but where the reference distribution is the census data, provided by me. Would this make sense? Would the test work if I were to normalise both the census and the patient data, to avoid the issue of difference in total numbers?  Would a different approach (e.g. a goodness of fit test, a permutation t-test, a shift function...) be preferable?

Bonus points if there is a way to set up the best solution in scipy.stats in python.